# Refactoring activities which differ only in data presented

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm writing an Android app in Android Studio with Kotlin. As I'm new to this, I had a wrong perception that every new 'shot' needs a new activity. I'm writing a story game with multiple shots.

So, my activities differ only by data.

There 2 types of repeating parts:

1st: only picture on the screen is changing with next-button press.

Code:

```
class Kadr1Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kadr01)
}

fun nextClick(view: View) {
    val intentKadr2 = Intent(this, Kadr2Activity::class.java) //every next button intents next shot
    startActivity(intentKadr2)
    this.finish()
}

fun backClick(view: View){
    val intentKadr0 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java) //every back button intents previous shot
    startActivity(intentKadr0)
    this.finish()
}
```

}

2nd: user should solve the task by clicking the correct answer.

Code:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kadr13)
}

var flag = false

fun nextClick(view: View) {

    val intentKadr14 = Intent(this, Kadr14Activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intentKadr14)
    this.finish()

}

fun backClick(view: View){
    val intentKadr12 = Intent(this, Kadr12Activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intentKadr12)
    this.finish()
}

fun btn1Click(view: View){
    ans131Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_1_chosen) //picture of chosen button is changed every time it is pressed
    ans132Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_2)
    ans133Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_3)
    flag = false
}

fun btn2Click(view: View){
    ans132Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_2_chosen)
    ans131Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_1)
    ans133Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_3)
    flag = true
}

fun btn3Click(view: View){
    ans133Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_3_chosen) 
    ans131Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_1)
    ans132Btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_13_2)
    flag = false
}
```

}

I've read that it would be better to get rid of repeating parts of code and refactor it somehow.

Could anyone give me a hint where I can actually find how to refactor my code? Would be very grateful.

Comment: Added code. I just want to understand how to get rid of repeating parts as most of the activities have the same code. I somehow might group them by those types, but I couldn't find any guide how to do it.

Comment: You can add data to the Intent that you use to start the next activity. That activity can use that data to select which data it shows, so you can do it all in the same Activity class, especially if it uses the same layout.